Taking hyperplane section map remains dominant
I was reading Kollar's book "Rational curves on algebraic varieties". This is from Chapter IV, proposition $1.3$. I don't understand the proof from $1.3.3$ to $1.3.1$, Page- 182. Suppose I have a dominant morphism $\mathbb{A}^1 \times Z \to X$ over an algebraically closed field $k$, where $Z, X$ are smooth varieties. Also assume that for some $z \in Z$ the map $\mathbb{A}^1 \times z \to X$ is non-constant. Then how to prove there is some smooth variety $Z^{\prime}$ such that $\dim(Z^{\prime}) = \dim(X) - 1$ with a dominant morphism $\mathbb{A}^1 \times Z^{\prime} \to X$. I am trying to do using hyperplane section of $Z$. But how to show taking suitable hyperplane section of $Z$ the map remains dominant.
Any suggestion or hint is highly appreciated.

Have you considered the incidence variety for the linear system of hyperplanes you're cutting by? This will allow you to use semicontinuity theorems.
